# How many StateMachines can Spring StateMachine have?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I get that the documentation mentions 'a' statement machine and further states for states 'for simple use cases'. The examples define annotations @StateMachine which does not bode well for my question.

What If I want to have a different StateMachine per business process to instead of trying to define one single increasingly complex state machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use [StateMachine factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#with-enablestatemachinefactory) and get new instance per business process.

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class BusinessProcessStateMachineConfig
        extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .initial(States.S1)
                .end(States.SF)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

}
```

You can then inject the factory in your services and get instances.
You can even have more than one factory (e.g. if you want to have totally different state machines in the same codebase).

```
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "one")
```

Specifying a name allows for multiple factories to exist and multiple sm instances of each factory to be injected in services.